# XSLT big integer (int64) handling msxml

Tags: xslt, types, msxml, biginteger

When trying to do math on an big integer (int64) large number in xslt template I get the wrong result since there is no native 64-bit integer support in xslt (xslt number is 64-bit double). I am using msxml 6.0 on Windows XP SP3. Are there any work around for this on Windows?

```
<tables>
  <table>
    <table_schem>REPADMIN</table_schem>
    <table_name>TEST_DESCEND_IDENTITY_BIGINT</table_name>
    <column>
      <col_name>COL1</col_name>
      <identity>
        <col_min_val>9223372036854775805</col_min_val>
        <col_max_val>9223372036854775805</col_max_val>
        <autoincrementvalue>9223372036854775807</autoincrementvalue>
        <autoincrementstart>9223372036854775807</autoincrementstart>
        <autoincrementinc>-1</autoincrementinc>
      </identity>
    </column>
  </table>
</tables>
```

This test returns true due to the inexact representation of the large integer in 64-bit double (I am assuming) but actually is false if I could tell the xslt processor somehow to use int64 rather than the default 64-bit double for the number data since big integer is the actual data type for numbers in the xml input.

```
          <xsl:when test="autoincrementvalue = 
                (col_min_val + autoincrementinc)">
            <xsl:value-of select="''"/>
          </xsl:when>
```

here is the complete template

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
  <!--Reseed Derby identity column-->
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration='yes' method='text' />
  <xsl:param name="stmtsep">;</xsl:param>
  <xsl:param name="schemprefix"></xsl:param>
  <xsl:template match="tables">
    <xsl:variable name="identitycount" select="count(table/column/identity)"></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:for-each select="table/column/identity">
      <xsl:variable name="table_schem" select="../../table_schem"></xsl:variable>
      <xsl:variable name="table_name" select="../../table_name"></xsl:variable>
      <xsl:variable name="tablespec">
        <xsl:if test="$schemprefix">
          <xsl:value-of select="$table_schem"/>.</xsl:if><xsl:value-of 
                        select="$table_name"/></xsl:variable>
      <xsl:variable name="col_name" select="../col_name"></xsl:variable>
      <xsl:variable name="newstart">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="autoincrementinc > 0">
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="col_max_val = '' and 
                        autoincrementvalue = autoincrementstart">
                <xsl:value-of select="''"/>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:when test="col_max_val = ''">
                <xsl:value-of select="autoincrementstart"/>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:when test="autoincrementvalue =
                    (col_max_val + autoincrementinc)">
                <xsl:value-of select="''"/>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:when test="(col_max_val + autoincrementinc) &lt; 
                        autoincrementstart">
                <xsl:value-of select="autoincrementstart"/>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="col_max_val + autoincrementinc"/>
              </xsl:otherwise>              
            </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="autoincrementinc &lt; 0">
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="col_min_val = '' and
                    autoincrementvalue = autoincrementstart">
                <xsl:value-of select="''"/>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:when test="col_min_val = ''">
                <xsl:value-of select="autoincrementstart"/>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:when test="autoincrementvalue = 
                    (col_min_val + autoincrementinc)">
                <xsl:value-of select="''"/>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:when test="(col_min_val + autoincrementinc) >
                        autoincrementstart">
                <xsl:value-of select="autoincrementstart"/>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="col_min_val + autoincrementinc"/>
              </xsl:otherwise>              
            </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:when>          
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:if test="not(position()=1)"><xsl:text>
</xsl:text></xsl:if>
      <xsl:choose>
        <!--restart with ddl changes both the next identity value AUTOINCREMENTVALUE and
        the identity start number AUTOINCREMENTSTART eventhough in this casewe only want 
        to change only the next identity number-->
        <xsl:when test="$newstart != '' and 
                        $newstart != autoincrementvalue">alter table <xsl:value-of 
select="$tablespec"/> alter column <xsl:value-of 
select="$col_name"/> restart with <xsl:value-of 
select="$newstart"/><xsl:if test="$identitycount>1">;</xsl:if></xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>-- reseed <xsl:value-of select="$tablespec"/> is not necessary</xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any work around for this on
>   Windows?

**No, unless you use an XSLT 2.0 processor, such as Saxon or AltovaXML**.

In XSLT 2.0 XPath 2.0 is used, which has support for xs:decimal and this gives you the required precision. With Saxon one can also use just xs:integer, because both Saxon and Altova implement Big Integer arithmetic.

**Here is an XSLT 2.0 stylesheet (that uses xs:integer by default)**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:value-of select=
     "9223372036854775805 + (-1)"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Both Saxon 9.x and AltovaXML2010 produce the following correct result**:

```
9223372036854775804
```

**Here is an XSLT 2.0 stylesheet that uses xs:decimal explicitly**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:value-of select=
     "xs:decimal(9223372036854775805) + (-1)"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Both Saxon 9.x and AltovaXML2010 again produce the correct result**

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am afraid I am stuck with msxml 6.0 for now. Since I am generating the input xml from the resultset of a sql select statement, a viable way of doing the math correctly is to do the math at the database select statement and add newstart element to the input xml; then the xslt processer will do no math at all and just check for empty string for $newstart to generate the output